# Azure application map shows multiple services as one

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-application-insights

I have demo petstore application hosted in azure written in java. It uses applicationinsights-agent-3.5.0.jar to auto instrument code for application insights (I also tried newer applicationinsights-agent-3.5.1.jar version).

Application has 4 web services that make calls to each other. However in azure app insights application maps it is shown as 1 service which makes calls to itself
[image]

Services are hosted at containerapps. And each service has APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING, APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY, APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_ROLE_INSTANCE env variables.

Basically every aspect of app insights works correctly except app map. For example in live metrics I can see 4 apps with my custom names
[image]

And in transaction search you can see that apps make http calls to each other
[image]

What may be the problem and how can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue by providing each service new environment variable APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_ROLE_NAME

Comment: Without this environment variable - where did `petstore-insights` come from? Is it a name of Application Insights resource where data was submitted?

Comment: It is app insights resource name